# Schema design for topics with ratings

Tags: scala, database-design, database-schema

I'm working on a new project where users rate articles. I have a list of topics/tags which, depending on how much of the blog post is related to that topic, are given a rating of 0-3.

0 meaning the topic has nothing to do with article and 3 meaning the topic has a lot to do with the article. The only problem is that each article has to have some relationship with all of the topics whether or not the topic has something to do with the article.

Here's what I came up with (there are actually 20 topics)

```
/**
 * Option 1
 *
 * for every article created, a tag will be
 * created for each topic all containing a reference
 * to the article
 */
trait Topic
object Topics {
  topic1 extends Topic
  topic2 extends Topic
  topic3 extends Topic
}

case class Article(id:Int, title:String, content:String)
case class Tag(id:Int, articleId:Int, topic:Topic)

/**
 * Option 2
 *
 * remember each topic has a rating 0-3
 * and there are actually about 20 total topics
 */
case class Article(id:Int, 
title:String, 
content:String, 
topic1:Int,
topic2:Int,
topic3:Int)

/**
 * Option 3
 *
 * topics with either a rating of 2 or 3
 * will be created with a reference to the article
 * and topics with a 0 with be created but inside a
 * "has_nothing_to_do_with_the_article" table
 * all the other topics will be not be created and will
 * just default to 1.
 */
```

Please, I'd be more than grateful for any advice. What are the best practices (as for as schema & db modeling) for something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your choice of DB.

1. 20 fields for 20 topics is possible, but is really ugly and may hit the limit of the 22-field in tuples or case classes of Scala.
2. If you're using NoSQL like mongodb, you can put a Map or Array into the Article class to represent the relationship.
3. If you're using traditional RDBMS, another possible way is to have another rating table modelling the ratings from article to topics.
4. Usually the best choice is to optimize and restrict general solutions to your specific scenario. If, as you said, the rating value is an integer from 0-3 and the topic is at most 20. You can encode these values into a Long integer and by providing helper methods in your model class to reach the best of both worlds.